# Error when reading a value from application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I created a value in application.rb file as follows

```
module RailsCron
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.myvalue = "test"
  end
end
```

and um trying to read the value from a controller as follows

```
directory_path = RailsCron::Application.config.myvalue
```

when i run it um getting the following error

```
 undefined method `myvalue' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000003e20560>
```

what could possibly get wrong um quite new to rails . Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It did work after I restart the server. I did not know that if I had add new for the application.rb file I need to restart the server

Comment: Same for initializers and environment files.

Comment: And files in lib. Safe bet is changes to all files except in the app folder, would need a restart.